# Extract single data value from retrieved firebase json objects

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my android app I want to retrieve only a single value from all the nodes of firebase json objects and check...
My firebase database looks like ->
[image]

Now i am using this code to achieve my task but I am getting null everytime  as output..

```
public class optChos extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseReference ref;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_opt_chos);

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference("vendorDtl");
}

public void fetchkey(View view) {
    EditText etx=findViewById(R.id.etkey);
    String keysrch=etx.getText().toString();
    Log.i("optionchoose","fetchkeycalled");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Key finfing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot vst:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                vendor vn = vst.getValue(vendor.class);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email is-> " + vn.getNam(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "key is-> " + vn.getVky(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"nothing fetched",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot vst:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                vendor vn = vst.getValue(vendor.class);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email is-> " + vn.getNam(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "key is-> " + vn.getVky(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"nothing fetched",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Here `fetchkey(View view)` is the onclick function of a button..

> I want to retrieve that `vid` from every node and check with a user
>   entered value ..How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of your `vid` field from every node, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference vendorDtlRef = rootRef.child("vendorDtl");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String vid = ds.child("vid").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", vid);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
vendorDtlRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: its showing  `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String` error in the logcat   @Alex Mamo

Comment: What is the type of your field, String or Long? I see in your screenshot that for the same field you have different values. You need both value to be the same. If the value should be Long, then replace that line of code with: `long vid = ds.child("vid").getValue(Long.class);` Does it work now?

Comment: ok.. thanks and if i use mix of chars and numbers..then string will work?right?

Comment: No, you must have the same type of data. In your screenshot, the fist vid is a String (`fzgnzj`) and the second is a Long (`32525`). Both must be the same. Make both strings, use the code in my answer and it will work 100%. It's ok now?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the `vid` from every node do this:

```
DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("vendorDTl");
                    data.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                String vid=data.child("vid").getValue().toString();
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

This will go to the datasnapshot location `vendorDTl` and then using that `for` loop it will iterate inside the children of that node to get the value `vid`